# The method has not found the correct data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection:

```
+items: Collection {#173 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      "2" => {#164 ▼
        +"name": "101 роза"
        +"price": 4999
        +"is_sale": 0
        +"sale_price": null
        +"sale_percent": null
        +"can_use_promocode": 1
        +"qty": 6
      }
    ]
  }
```

then, I try to use method `has()` to check if this product is already exists in cart:

```
if ($this->items->has($productId)) {
     $this->items->$productId->qty++;
}
```

But this does not work. Tried to do:

```
dump($this->items->has($productId));
```

But I got only `false`. Where did I go wrong?

And am I right to do `$this->items->$productId->qty++;`, will it work?

UPD:

output for `dump($this->items, $productId, $this->items->has($productId), $this->items->has(2));`:

```
Collection {#172 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "2" => {#163 ▼
      +"name": "101 rose"
      +"price": 4999
      +"is_sale": 0
      +"sale_price": null
      +"sale_percent": null
      +"can_use_promocode": 1
      +"qty": 1
    }
  ]
}

"2"

false

false
```

If it will helps: Laravel 5.2.45, I took the data from here (get it from database and save in class variable):

```
    class Cart
{

    public $items;

    public $promocode;

    public $delivery;

    protected $id;

    private $lastUpdate;

    private $request;


    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->id = ($request->cookie('cart_id')) ? $request->cookie('cart_id') : false;
        $this->getCart();
    }
    private function getCart() {
        if (!$this->id) {
            $newCart = $this->setNewCart();

            $id = $newCart->id;

            $cart = $newCart->cart;
        } else {
            $cart = CartModel::where('id', '=', $this->id)->select('value')->first();

            if (!$cart) {
                $newCart = $this->setNewCart();
                $cart = $newCart->cart;
                $this->id = $newCart->id;
            } else {
                $cart = $cart->value;
            }

            $cart = json_decode($cart);
            $this->lastUpdate = $cart->lastUpdate;
            $this->items = collect($cart->items);
            $this->promocode = $cart->promocode;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked 3 questions about collections already, just test them yourself using tinker... (`php artisan tinker`). Is it really worth wasting your time writing up questions when you can solve the issue yourself in less time? [Here is a free book on collections you can download](https://leanpub.com/laravelcollectionsunraveled).

Comment: @Kyslik I've asked this questions, just because I cant understand where I go wrong (I have followed the documentation in all cases). As example, check this question. There's a key `"2"`, but method `has()` returns false. What should I test here?

Comment: That depends on how you get "your collection" that is missing from the question, either way you should figure out answers to your questions yourself and run for answer on SO as last resort.

Comment: Are you sure that `productId` is equal to `2`? The collection and `has(2)` lookup are correct, so the problem must be with your `productId` variable. Try changing `has($productId)` to `has(2)` to confirm this, then `dump($productId)` to see the value.

Comment: @sam checked it, my `$productId` is `2`, and I tried to make `dump($this->items->has('2'))`, it returns `false`

Comment: Please share the output of the following code: `dump($this->items, $productId, $this->items->has($productId), $this->items->has(2));`.

Comment: @sam added to question

Comment: @Alexxosipov as you can see in the output you've provided, `$productId` has no value. You need to make sure that `$productId` has a value.

Comment: @sam oh, it's my fault, I missed it in `dump()`. Updated the question one more time (`$productId` equals to `"2"`)

Comment: I've answered the question for you. For future reference, when you're seeking help with a problem like this -- one where you're experiencing the unexpected -- it's almost certainly an issue with how you're doing things rather than an issue with the framework you're using, therefore it's imperative that you include as much of the code you've wrote as possible to allow others to understand what you're doing and how it might be causing the issue :) You should start out a question like this with all of the relevant code, rather than sharing a small portion that you *think* is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing additional code. The problem is caused by your use of json: you're encoding and then decoding json and that is creating an array of objects, not an array of associative arrays.

`json_decode` accepts a parameter `assoc` which "[when `true` returned objects will be converted into associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)" so you need to pass this parameter.

Replace this:

```
$cart = json_decode($cart);
```

With this:

```
$cart = json_decode($cart, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a collection to an array, add the data and then convert it back to a collection:

```
$array = $collection->toArray();
$array[$key]['qty']++;
$collection = collect($array);
```

Or, you can update collection with [`pull()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pull) and [`put()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-put):

```
$item = $collection->pull($key);
$item['qty']++;
$collection->put($key, $item);
```

Comment: Thank you! But my trouble here is why method `has()` does not return `true`? I got an item with key `"2"`, but this is does not work :C

Comment: @Alexxosipov the key looks like it's string and not an integer, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Alexxosipov you also cannot do this `$this->items->$productId->qty++;`, I thought this was the problem and I've shown you how to modify the data instead of using `$this->items->$productId->qty++;`.

Comment: No, this is the second trouble here, and this is not so important. First is about method `has()` and my collection

Comment: @Alexxosipov put `dump($this->items->has('2'))` before you're trying to modify the collection in any way.

Comment: @Alexxosipov could you give some data sample to play with? Also, please show how exactly you're creating the collection and what version of Laravel you use.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: @Alexxosipov you're doing a lot of weird and redundant stuff. You do not need to `json_decode()` the collection. Also, if `items` is a relationship, you shouldn't collect it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Has looks for a key, you are passing in a value. You probably want to use `where` or something similar if you are looking for a matching item.

Comment: But in my case, `(["2" => [....)`, I need to search with keys, not with values. Or I'm wrong?